# Avoid base64 encoding on my data sent to Event Hub via Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub

I am sending a json object(in python) to Azure Event Hub which is routed to Blob Storage via Event Capture feature of Event Hub. This file gets stored in Apache AVRO. When I upload the file on online AVRO reader I see something like this ..[AVRO Reader Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaK8P.png)

The actual data is in body of the image. I don't want Azure Event Hub to encode my data to base64. What changes should I make to my below code.

```
    
    producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=EVENTHUB_CONNECTION_STR, eventhub_name=eventhub)
    
    async with producer:
        dictionary_obj = {}
        dictionary_obj['id'] = 1
        dictionary_obj['Name'] = 'Alex'
        dictionary_obj['Attr1'] = 1
        MESSAGE = json.dumps(dictionary_obj)
        event_data_batch = await producer.create_batch()
        event_data_batch.add(EventData(MESSAGE))
        await producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)
        await producer.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Event Hubs handles the data in the message body as an opaque byte array. It never encodes it prior to avro write.